# TFTP isn't listening the defined port when started using a xinetd rule

Tags: tftp, xinetd

I am following [this](https://oplossing.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/how-to-setup-tftp-on-ubuntu-11-10/) tutorial to work with tftp:

First, I install all the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd tftpd tftp -y
```

Next, create a configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
```

Put the following content into the file.

```
service tftp
{
   protocol = udp
   port = 69
   socket_type = dgram
   wait = yes
   user = nobody
   server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
   server_args = var/lib/tftpboot -s
   disable = no
}
```

Now I change the ownership of the directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tftpboot
sudo chown -R nobody:nobody /var/lib/tftpboot
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/tftpboot
```

and start the TFTP service:

```
sudo service xinetd stop
sudo service xinetd start
```

Then verify the TFTP is running correctly or not:

```
    root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/home/ravi# netstat -na | grep LIST | grep 69
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16171    @/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1692
root@ravi-Inspiron-N5010:/home/ravi#
```

The output of the netstat is different from what is mentioned in the tutorial:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:69              0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN
```

Comment: Sorry, why do you expecting TCP port listening? TFTP is UDP-based protocol. And you've configured xinetd to listen UDP 69. Try to use 'netstat -anpu | grep 69' to find TFTP port opened.

Answer (score 6):

TFTP is a UDP-based protocol and, as such, you won't find a line which says LISTEN or LISTENING.

Run `netstat -na | grep udp`

and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

As stated previously output looks legit enough. Here's the thing though, have you actually tried accessing the TFTP server via the client. Only sure fire way to know whether or not it's listening...

One thing is that one of the steps may need to be changed if this is Ubuntu. Basically it should be:

> `sudo service xinetd restart`

not

> `sudo service xinetd stop`
>
> `sudo service xinetd start`
>
> only step 4 needs to be changed, since xinetd is spawned by upstart. you need to restart it with 'service xinetd restart' –  BЈовић Sep 4 '13 at 12:14
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/201505/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-tftp-server

Another alternative is to simply try a different TFTP (tftpd-hpa, atftpd, etc...) server to get things running...

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-configure-tftp-server-ubuntu-debian-howto/

Answer (score 0):

you did not mention which tutorial you'd followed.
However, output seems quite legit. tftp does use xinetd wrapper so you'll see connection in netstat only if there is actually connected client. Give it a try and then run netstat again with

```
netstat -tupan
```

make sure your firewall does allow connection to the port:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <your subnet> -p tcp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s <your subnet> -p udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
```

where "your subnet" is kind of 192.168.1.0/24